# Highcharts. During export chart labels are cropped

Tags: highcharts, export

[Image here (PNG format)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igSWu.png)

Exported image in SVG format looks ok, but labels in PNG, JPEG or PDF format images are cropped. 
marginRight, marginLeft, width, sourceWidth changes make no sense.

This is my chart [Chart](https://maxmonitor.am/mediatrend/highcharts.html)

Comment: Could you provide us with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example? We didn't saw your code at all, so we don't know what are the options you pass into the chart constructor. It is necessary to see that things in order to help you

Comment: I've edited the post..  Here is my chart ( https://maxmonitor.am/mediatrend/highcharts.html ) . You know, looks like labels are in unicode format, that's why something goes wrong. When I use english labels then everything is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a bit old version of Highcharts, so first, please update it at least to `v4.1.8`. Then, please try to set options below within your chart configuration object:

Enable html support for exporting:

```
exporting: {
    allowHTML: true
}
```

and switch on the `useHTML` on the `xAxis.labels`:

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
       useHTML: true
    }
}
```

API Reference:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.useHTML

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.allowHTML